# Tomcat 7 startup issue using STS 3.0.1

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I've installed STS 3.0.1 and I'm following along with my book Pro Spring MVC with Web Flow (from APress).

I've imported the source code provided by the book/publisher into STS. I've added the Tomcat7 server and selected the Tomcat7 as Targeted Runtime.

I've set Tomcat7 to use JDK 1.6. And STS seems to be using JDK 1.6 as well, per what I have configured.

I can use Gradle to build my project, move the war file to the webapps folder, manually restart Tomcat7 (outside of Eclipse) and it'll work.

However, from STS itself, when I select Run as -> Run on server, I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/chapter1-bookstore]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/chapter1-bookstore]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method addServlet(String, DispatcherServlet) is undefined for the type ServletContext

    at com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web.BookstoreWebApplicationInitializer.registerDispatcherServlet(BookstoreWebApplicationInitializer.java:49)
    at com.apress.prospringmvc.bookstore.web.BookstoreWebApplicationInitializer.onStartup(BookstoreWebApplicationInitializer.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5274)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
9-Nov-2012 11:14:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
9-Nov-2012 11:14:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
9-Nov-2012 11:14:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4465 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why, but I switched to STS 3.1.0 instead of Groovy/Grails Suite 3.1.0 (no idea why went with that in the first place).

Now, the tutorials and explanations I've gotten so far all work. Woot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this

The method addServlet(String, DispatcherServlet) is undefined for the type ServletContext

If you check the javadoc it can be seen that the addServlet method did not exist in JavaEE5

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html

That means that your Tomcat7 tries to use the Tomcat6 configurations. In eclipse open the server tab, double click the tomcat 7 installation. Then check if the runtime dropdown is set to Tomcat7. Additionally you can click the "Open launch configuration" and see if the lirbaries are set up correctly. If none of that helps, you can try to delete your tomcat instance from eclipse and try to create a new one.

Comment: Runtime Environment shows Tomcat 7... Open Launch Configuration > [Classpath looks like this](http://i.imgur.com/4NC0h.png)

Comment: one more thing you can check. Create a new tomcat server in eclipse. In the new server window click Configure runtime environments, then edit the tomcat 7 runtime and check if the Tomcat installation points to the right tomcat path. If yes, see if the new server works...

Comment: [New Server Screen](http://i.imgur.com/9NKAF.png)... [Server Runtime](http://i.imgur.com/eWVfj.png)... still the same error... Nothing to do with the use of JDk 1.6?

Comment: I use it with JDK1.6 as well, just out of curiosity is it possible to download the example project from somewhere?

Comment: I did chapter 1 from the downloaded components at this address: http://www.apress.com/9781430241553

Comment: I also have Tomcat 7 and Java6 and it works for me. I have no concrete idea, try to update eclipse and the tomcat plugin to the latest...